# Extract Redux Store/State as Selector

Tags: javascript, redux

Currently I'm having to reconfigure my store to create selector. Is there a better way to do this.

```
import { configureStore } from "../configureStore";
const { store } = configureStore();

export const getSession = () => store.getState().session.data || false;
export const getToken = () => store.getState().session.data.token || false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selector functions should take the store state as the argument, not capture the store reference.  As an example:

```
export const getSession = (state) => state.session.data || false;
export const getToken = (state) => state.session.data.token || false;

// use like:
const session = getSession(store.getState());
```

See my post [Idiomatic Redux: Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for more details.

Comment: I think you missed an `=` sign.  

    `export const getSession = (state) => state.session.data || false;`

    `export const getToken = (state) => state.session.data.token || false;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Redux in React world, then you should definitely attach the redux store to the props of a React component by using `connect` (https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

That way, whenever the values in the store changes, you get updated props provided to your component, re-rendering the component with the correct values.

With that, you generally don't ever need `store.getState()`.  You do something like:

```
// selectors.js
const getSession = state => state.session.data || false

// component.js
const MyComponent = ({ session }) => <div>{session}</div>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  session: getSession(state),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```